Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability showing up when Android app is pre-Launch to the Playstore
Recently i creat new app from playstore console and also upload new bundle but playstore mention security and trust issues like Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability. this issues shows following places . anyone help me how solve this issue.
private fun performAction(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val apiKey = intent.getStringExtra(VideoChatConstants.API_KEY)
    val sessionId = intent.getStringExtra(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY)
    val token = intent.getStringExtra(VideoChatConstants.TOKEN_KEY)
    val caller = intent.getStringExtra(VideoChatConstants.OTHER_PARTY_EXTRA_KEY)
    val imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(VideoChatConstants.IMAGE_URL_KEY)
    val notifId = intent.getIntExtra(VideoChatConstants.NOTIFCATION_ID_EXTRA_KEY, -1)
    Logger.debug(TAG, "performAction:: notifId= $notifId")

    when(intent.action) {
        VideoChatConstants.CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION_VALUE -> {
            context.startActivity(
                Intent(context.applicationContext, VideoChatActivity::class.java)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.API_KEY, apiKey)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY, sessionId)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.TOKEN_KEY, token)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.OTHER_PARTY_EXTRA_KEY, caller)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.IMAGE_URL_KEY, imgUrl)
            )
            context.stopService(Intent(context, CallNotificationService::class.java))
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS))
            } /*else {
                UCHNotificationManager.cancelNotification(context,
                        notifId)
            }*/
        }
        VideoChatConstants.CALL_DIALOG_ACTION_VALUE -> {
            context.startActivity(
                Intent(context, CallRingingActivity::class.java)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                    or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.API_KEY, apiKey)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY, sessionId)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.TOKEN_KEY, token)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.OTHER_PARTY_EXTRA_KEY, caller)
                    .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.IMAGE_URL_KEY, imgUrl)
            )
        }
        VideoChatConstants.CALL_CANCEL_ACTION_VALUE -> {
            context.stopService(
                Intent(context, CallNotificationService::class.java)
                .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY, sessionId)
            )
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS))
            }
            VideoCallManager.getInstance()
                .onVideoCallRejected(sessionId,
                                object: VideoCallManager.VideoCallCallback {
                                    override fun onResults(isSuccess: Boolean) {
                                        if(isSuccess) {
                                            Logger.debug(TAG, "Call reject is acknowledged by server")
                                        } else {
                                            Logger.warn(TAG, "Call reject is NOT acknowledged by server!")
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
        }
        VideoChatConstants.CALL_HANGED_UP_ACTION_VALUE -> {
            context.stopService(
                    Intent(context, CallNotificationService::class.java)
                            .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY, sessionId)
            )
            context.sendBroadcast(Intent(VideoChatConstants.CALL_DISCONNECTED_ACTION))
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS))
            }
        }
        else -> {
            Logger.warn(TAG, "intent action is unexpectedly null!")
        }
    }
}

same issue mention other place aslo
if(pushType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.NotificationTypes.VIDEO_CALLING.name())) {
            if(pushTime != null && !CommonUtils.isHalfMinuteOrLess(pushTime)) {
                Logger.debug(TAG, "Obsolete video call push, ignore");
                return;
            }
            if(VideoChatService.Companion.isOnline()) {
                // already in another call, reject this one
                VideoCallManager.Companion.getInstance().onVideoCallRejected(notificationInfo.getSessionId(), new VideoCallManager.VideoCallCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResults(boolean isSuccess) {
                                Logger.debug(TAG, "Rejected the call since another call is ongoing. " +
                                        "isSuccess= " + isSuccess);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Logger.debug(TAG, "incoming call, session ID=" + notificationInfo.getSessionId());
                AppPref.updatePref(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY, notificationInfo.getSessionId());
                callNotificationIntent = new Intent(context, CallNotificationService.class)
                        .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.OTHER_PARTY_EXTRA_KEY, notificationInfo.getCallerName())
                        .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.IMAGE_URL_KEY, notificationInfo.getCallerImage())
                        .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.API_KEY, notificationInfo.getApiKey())
                        .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.SESSION_ID_KEY, notificationInfo.getSessionId())
                        .putExtra(VideoChatConstants.TOKEN_KEY, notificationInfo.getToken());

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    context.startForegroundService(callNotificationIntent);
                } else {
                    context.startService(callNotificationIntent);
                }
            }

        }

Actually this code used for video call and also we used video call library
 <service
            android:name=".videochat.service.CallNotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="phoneCall" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".videochat.receiver.CallNotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="CALL_RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="CALL_CANCEL" />
                <action android:name="CALL_DIALOG" />
                <action android:name="CALL_HANGED_UP" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".util.NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="REPLY_REMOTE" />
                <action android:name="DISMISS_REMOTE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



This might be because you are passing an API key through the intent. Try using Build Config if possible.

here we fetch api key initialize call time only. here How using Build Config ? any other idea
